# Can a responsive svg (with fluid aspect ratio) contain a pattern with fixed aspect ratio?

Tags: svg

I'd like to define an inline `<svg>` in an HTML document which has a fixed height (e.g. 50px) and a dynamic width (e.g. 100%), within which is a polyline filled with a pattern (e.g. a checked pattern). I'd like the polyline to be scaled to fill the `svg` area (i.e. its aspect ratio is not preserved), but I *would* like the pattern's aspect ratio to be preserved (so the squares in the check pattern remain square).

I see that `<pattern>` has a `preserveAspectRatio` attribute, but naively setting it to `xMinYMin meet` didn't seem to have an effect in this situation, as you can see in the below snippet:

```css
svg {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern-checked" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="black" />
            <rect x="20" y="20" width="20" height="20" fill="black" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polyline fill="url(#pattern-checked)" points="0,100 20,50 50,0 70,30, 100,100" />
</svg>
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want (ideally without any JS that depends on the measured width of the element)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to use the polygon as a clip-path for a div and use the two rects as a background image in css.

Please observe that [clipPathUnits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clipPathUnits) is set to `objectBoundingBox` and the polygon has a `transform="scale(0.01)"` making the bounding box a square of 1 user unit value

```css
#pattern {
  padding: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: url(#clip);  
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 40 40' width='20'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='20' height='20' fill='black' /%3E%3Crect x='20' y='20' width='20' height='20' fill='black' /%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
 
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" class="svg-clip" style="position:absolute">
    <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
           <polyline points="0,100 20,50 50,0 70,30, 100,100" transform="scale(0.01)" />
        </clipPath>       
    </defs>
</svg>

<div id="pattern"></div>
```

OBSERVATION: In order to encode the svg for the css background I've used this [SVG-encoder](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/MWKeKK)

Comment: Thanks! This has actually made me realise I can (in my specific case and specific patterns) ditch the svg entirely and just use a div with `clip-path: polygon(...)` and `background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(...)`. This looks like a good general solution to the question I asked, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a second variant to enxaneta's solution, the same could be done only in SVG. If you **don't** define a viewBox for the root `<svg>`, a `<rect width="100%" height="100%">` will fill the whole element, and you can apply both the pattern (filling it using userspace coordinates) and the clip path (applied in object bounding box fractions).

```css
svg {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
           <polyline points="0,100 20,50 50,0 70,30, 100,100" transform="scale(0.01)" />
        </clipPath>
        <pattern id="pattern-checked" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="black" />
            <rect x="20" y="20" width="20" height="20" fill="black" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-checked)" clip-path="url(#clip)" />
</svg>
```